# Trying not to count compound words in dummy variable

Tags: r

I am trying to make a dummy variable for product without also grabbing compound words that include product. In the output above it counts "productdesign" as 1 in tags$product. I am trying to find the syntax to strictly grab "product".

```
library(NLP)
library(tm)
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
library(topicmodels)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
#sample dataset
tags <- c("product productdesign electronicdevice", "productdesign electronicdevice")
web <- c("hardware", "sunglasses")
tags <- data_frame(tags, web)
tags <- mutate(tags, product = ifelse(grepl("product", tags), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610 -- can you reduce your sample code to just what we need to help with this problem (that is, pull the libraries we don't need) and provide a sample of the output you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include `\\b` to indicate the boundary of the word or `\\sproduct\\s` to include the space before and after the word `product`

```
> tags <- mutate(tags, product = ifelse(grepl("\\bproduct\\b", tags), 1, 0))
> tags
# A tibble: 2 x 3
                                    tags        web product
                                   <chr>      <chr>   <dbl>
1 product productdesign electronicdevice   hardware       1
2         productdesign electronicdevice sunglasses       0
>
```